Pyspark DAGScheduler: Failed to update accumulator because of Pyspark UDF?
When I run a UDF on pyspark I get this on the console all the time. It hasnt failed any unittest yet which prompts me to question if this is something I need to attend to? but this is my first time using UDF and this error does not have sufficient documentation on.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: EOF reached before Python server acknowledged
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2.merge(PythonRDD.scala:751)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$updateAccumulators$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1694)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$updateAccumulators$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1685)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.updateAccumulators(DAGScheduler.scala:1685)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:1833)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3054)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2994)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2983)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
24/06/13 00:33:27 ERROR DAGScheduler: Failed to update accumulator 446 (org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2) for task 1
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:420)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:826)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1035)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
        at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:128)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2.merge(PythonRDD.scala:747)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$updateAccumulators$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1694)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$updateAccumulators$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1685)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.updateAccumulators(DAGScheduler.scala:1685)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:1833)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3054)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2994)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2983)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
24/06/13 00:33:27 ERROR DAGScheduler: Failed to update accumulator 446 (org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2) for task 4
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:420)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:826)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1035)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
        at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:128)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2.merge(PythonRDD.scala:747)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$updateAccumulators$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1694)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$updateAccumulators$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1685)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.updateAccumulators(DAGScheduler.scala:1685)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:1833)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3054)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2994)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2983)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)

I have tried to comment out the function that is causing the issue and the issue is gone. here is the implementation
from dateutil.parser import parse

class:
    @functions.udf(returnType=StringType())
    def _parse_datetime(value: str) -> str:
        if value:
            return parse(value).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        return None

    def aFunction():
        dataframe = dataframe.withColumn(columnName, class._parse_datetime(columnName))

I want to just parse all the dates in pyspark but pyspark can only parse in yyyy-mm-dd which is why I used a UDF.
